# TFS reads a C# string incorrect

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tfs

So, this is an odd one:

I have a TFS 2015 (Update 3) running my tests from a smaller program.
I do unit tests on my code, and recently set TFS up to do them as well. Then suddenly *a wild error* appears in a simple math function - on the TFS, but not on my own machine.

Starting with the test output from TFS, where I cropped for relevant data:
[image]

And here for my local host's test:
[image]

The difference can be found in `Raw Input: 561077866` (for TFS) and `Raw Input: 5610.77866` (for local host).

**TFS forgets about the dot!**

So - where does it go wrong?

The test being run:

[image]

Predefined data - this will not change. Then I call a class object which stores the data in a `string` in the object - **this is where it goes wrong**:

[image]

Then I call the getter-property `Latitude` to perform some simple math:

[image]

---

**EDIT**:

So it turns out, that TFS reads Danish, while local host reads English.
The Danish language uses `,` to separate decimal and integers, while the English language uses `.`.

Comment: Check `CultureInfo.NumberFormat ` on both machine.

Comment: "So it turns out, that TFS reads Danish, while local host reads English." -- You can make that an answer instead of an edit. (Or delete your question if you feel like it, as long as there isn't an answer yet.)

Comment: That will most likely become part of the answer, @hvd, but I haven't solved the issue yet.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Can I specify this for the program, so that everywhere it runs it will be the same, but not for every code piece I pass a ``string`` with numbers in?

Comment: Refer to this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ddietric/2008/02/05/yacvcp-yet-another-currentculture-vs-currentuiculture-post/)

Comment: @RasmusBækgaard Eh? I figured you figured out already that to make it work, just make sure that the current culture is set to English. By changing the server configuration, by setting the current culture globally in your application, by explicitly passing the culture to `double.Parse`, whichever has your preference.